# Type does not conform to protocol QueryableDataSourceProtocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, reactivekit

I'm upgrading from Swift 2.3 to 3.0 (in Xcode 8.2.1), so I've updated the podfile (to no longer restrict the versions of the pods). My project uses Bond ( https://github.com/ReactiveKit/Bond ), and the current version of Bond is 6.2.8, which fails to compile as seen in the attached screenshot.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

[image]